# On memory allocation in armadillo sparse matrices

Tags: c++, memory-management, armadillo

I want to know whether I need to free up the memory occupied by `locations` and `values` objects after sparse matrix has been created. Here is the code:

```
void load_data(umat &locations, vec& values){
  // fill up locations and values
}

int main(int argc, char**argv){
    umat loc;
    vec val;
    load_data(loc,val);
    sp_mat X(loc,val);
    return 0;
}
```

In the above code, `load_data()` fills up the `locations` and `values` objects and then sparse matrix is created in `main()`. My Q: Do I need to free up memory used by locations and values after construction of `X`? The reason is that `X` could be large and I am on low RAM. I know when main returns, OS will free up `locations` and `values` as well as `X`. But, the real question is whether the memory occupied by `X` is the same as by `locations`and `values` OR `X` is allocated memory separately and I need to free `locations` and `values` in the case.

Comment: it should be written in the docs of the lib. if not,1. put a breakpoint before load_data, check the memory size used by your executable. 2. load a considerably large data and find the memory size change. 3. run the sp_mat line and see if the memory increase rate is close to the secon step. if it's the same delete it, otherwise don't. But, i believe there exists a better way to check it:)

Comment: Why don't you look at the Armadillo source code for the _SpMat_ class? `include/armadillo_bits/SpMat_meat.hpp`

Answer (score 1):

The constructor (SpMat_meat.hpp:231) you are using

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
inline SpMat(const Base<uword,T1>& locations, const Base<eT,T2>&  values, const bool sort_locations = true);
```

fills the sparse matrix with *copies* of the values in `values`.

I understand you are worried that you will run out of memory and if you keep `loc`, `val` and `X` separately you basically have two copies of the same data, taking up twice as much memory as actually needed (this is indeed what happens in your code snippet), so I will try to focus on addressing this problem and give you a few options:

1) If you are fine with keeping two copies of the data for a short while, the easiest solution is to *dynamically* allocate `loc` and `val` and delete them right after initialization of `X`

```
int main(int argc, char**argv){
    umat* ploc;
    vec* pval;
    load_data(*ploc,*pval); 
    // at this point we have one copy of the data
    sp_mat X(*ploc,*pval); 
    // at this point we have two copies of the data
    delete ploc;
    delete pval;
    // at this point we have one copy of the data

    return 0;
}
```

Of course you can use safe pointers instead of C style ones, but you get the idea.

2) If you absolutely don't want to have two copies of the data at any time, I would suggest that you modify your `load_data` routine to sequentially load values one by one and directly insert them into `X`

```
void load_data(umat &locations, vec& values, sp_mat& X){
 // fill up locations and values one by one into X
}
```

Other options would be to i) use move semantics to directly *move* the values in `val` into `X` or ii) directly use the memory allocated for `val` as the memory for `X`, similar to the advanced constructor for matrices

```
Mat(eT* aux_mem, const uword aux_n_rows, const uword aux_n_cols, const bool copy_aux_mem = true, const bool strict = false)
```

Both options would however require modifications on the level of the armadillo library, as such a functionality is not supplied yet for sparse matrices (There is only a plain move constructor so far). It would be a good idea to request these features from the developers though!

Comment: Thanks for your ans. I found the ans. though. As per armadillo, it allocates memory on heap and it is separate from `locations` and `values`. I can free-up memory right after allocating X. For your second option, it is very costly to fill-up X one-by-one. As Armadillo docs says that batch insertion is quite fast. I found the same while I tried your second solution. It is really time-consuming. The reason is that X is sparse and every time you fill it up, it looks for locations that are randomly distributed in a large array. It takes some overhead to do that.